# Can Bing or GMaps API do a "find my nearest" style search using a supplied XML/RSS collection?

Tags: xml, api, google-maps, geolocation, bing-maps

Can either Bing or Google Maps allow you to pass in a collection of points and then interrogate that collection to only plot the X nearest points?

I am asking because it may be difficult to pre-filter this data and would be much simpler to supply the entire list and filter it within the API itself.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to do most of the legwork yourself, the APIs aren't going to do every function under the sun for you.

However, I know that you can find the distance between two points using the Google Maps API. Take a look at the `distanceFrom` method in the [API reference](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/reference.html#GLatLng). It would only be a matter of calculating the distances for every point in your XML file, then taking the smallest X numbers.

Regarding your comment - yeah I guess looping through 300 items on the client-side might be a bit much. One solution would be to store the GPS coordinates for each point in your XML file (if not already), then create a function that would prune away most of the points using a simple distance calculator (you'd have to research that yourself). Then pass the remaining points (maybe 30 of them) into the API to calculate more accurate distances.

Comment: There are likely to be around 300+ items in the XML in some cases so I wanted to steer clear of looping through all of them if at all possible.

I'd be happy to do this filtering myself but the CMS supplying this data won't be able to hence my wondering if Google or Bing can do it instead.

Comment: @Simon: You could perhaps do a little pre-processing yourself and remove any obvious outliers, etc. I'll update my answer.

Comment: If you have the lat and lon for every point in the collection and you want the distance (the distance that is messured in a straight line) to a given point, then you can use the Havesine function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just looking at doing this for a client request i've had.  As far as I can see, the best way to do it would be to use Google (or similar) to [Geocode](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/) your addresses when they're entered (that is, turn a postal address into a latitude and longitude).

When you come to 'find my nearest', you'll want to get a postcode (probably) of the person searching and then geocode it, or maybe a lat-long if you're able to get the data straight out of a mobile device.

Once you have the lat-long for your fixed positions, and the same for your user, I reckon you can use a [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) (I say this, but I haven't actually tried it - I'm no mathematician) which is a mathematical way of calculating the distance between two points around a sphere.  The Earth isn't quite a sphere, but close enough for this sort of purpose.

This way, you're only doing one lookup to an external service to find your users location (assuming you've geocoded your fixed points when they were created, and stored them for later), and then doing the donkey work server side to calculate the distances.  You could probably even create a custom SQL function to pull it right out of the database in order.